# seleniumでダウンロードしてきたファイルをデスクトップに保存したい

Tags: python3, selenium

#### 前提・実現したいこと

python selenium でダウンロードしてきたファイルをデスクトップに保存したいです。
やり方は↓サイトで載っている通りにしたのですが、デフォルトダウンロードの「Downloads」フォルダに落ちてきてしまいます。
https://qiita.com/py_maro/items/6e79e4049677cf43c398
↑のサイトに書いてあることをそのまましています。

どこがまずいのでしょうか？
グーグルクロームを使用しています。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
特にエラーはありません。
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
#ダウンロード先のフォルダ指定
#使用例：
#download_directory='r:\\Users\\<あなたのホームディレクトリ>\\Downloads'
#注意点：バックスラッシュ(\)は、”\\"とエスケープ文字付きで記載する必要あり
download_directory='r:\\Users\\********\\Desktop'

###############################################################
### ダイアログを表示せずにファイルをダウンロードできます。
### ファイルはdownload_directoryで設定したパスに保存されます。
#
#使用例:
#   driver =init_selenium()
#   target_url='www.WannaGetFileFromHere.com'
#   driver.get(target_url)
###############################################################
def init_selenium():
    ###Chromeへオプションを設定
    chop = webdriver.ChromeOptions() #
    prefs = {"download.default_directory" : download_directory}
    chop.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
    chop.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors') #SSLエラー対策
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chop)
    return driver
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

- Python 3.7.3
- Windows7
- jupyter notebook
- chromedriver

Answer (score 1):

いくつか情報が合わさって混乱しているのかもしれませんが、質問時の記述ミスでは無いとしたら、ドライブ名が`r:`になっています。

`R:`ドライブは存在しないのでは？

ここは`c:`または`C:`ではないでしょうか？

---

**追記**

実験してみましたが、デスクトップへのダウンロードには以下のオプションが`prefs`設定に必要なようです。これが無いとデスクトップフォルダを指定してもダウンロードフォルダへダウンロードとなりました。
下記参考記事ではさらに2つのオプションが指定されていますが、それは無くても大丈夫でした。

```
"download.directory_upgrade" : True
```

参考：
[How to control the download of files with Selenium + Python bindings in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40654358/9014308)

> The path you declared for the default directory is invalid. Either escape the back slashes or provide a literal string.
>
> ```
> options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
> options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
>   "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\xxx\downloads\Test",
>   "download.prompt_for_download": False,
>   "download.directory_upgrade": True,
>   "safebrowsing.enabled": True
> })
> driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
> ```
>
> Here are the available preferences:
>   https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/pref_names.cc

Comment: 解決しました！ありがとうございます！