# Python seleniumでPDFを好きなディレクトリに保存したい

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, pdf

Python selenium でダウンロードしてきたファイルを指定したディレクトリに保存したいです．
↓サイトを参考にしましたが“Downloads”フォルダに入ってしまいます．
https://qiita.com/KWS_0901/items/33ae052e2e4694a6b4f1
↓サイトの方法を試しましたが解決しませんでした．
[https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61642/seleniumでダウンロードしてきたファイルをデスクトップに保存したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61642/selenium%E3%81%A7%E3%83%80%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8D%E3%81%9F%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E3%83%87%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%81%AB%E4%BF%9D%E5%AD%98%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

具体的な目標: Google検索でfiletype:pdfを使ってPDFのURLを収集して，requestsで直接ダウンロードして，requestsでダウンロードできなかったファイルをseleniumでダウンロードする

気づいたこと: PDFのURLは少なくとも2種類に分けられます．
1. クリックした瞬間ダウンロードのポップアップが出るもの
2. 印刷しないとダウンロードが始まらないもの
1.のURLの末尾には“php?”が含まれていることが多いです．下記スクリプトで1.をダウンロードするときは指定したディレクトリにダウンロードされますが，同じスクリプトで2.をダウンロードすると“Downloads”に保存されます．1.のダウンロードの際にChromeの左下にダウンロードバーが表示されますが2.ではダウンロードバーは表示されません．

paramsの設定が部分的に適応されていることから—kiosk-printingに問題があるように感じます．

環境:
macOS 12.3 Beta
Python 3.9.9
selenium 4.1.0
Google Chrome 98.0.4758.102 (Official Build) (x86_64)
chromedriver 98.0.4758.80 (webdriver_manager)

以下スクリプト

```
# https://qiita.com/KWS_0901/items/33ae052e2e4694a6b4f1
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import service as fs
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
#from pathlib import Path
import os
import time
import json

# 保存対象URL一覧取得
urls = []
with open('urls.txt', mode='rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    urls = f.readlines()

# Chrome の印刷機能でPDFとして保存
#options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options = Options()

# PDF印刷設定
appState = {
    "recentDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": ""
        }
    ],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2,
    "pageSize": 'A4'
}

downloadsFilePath = ''

# ドライバへのPDF印刷設定の適用
"""
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState": json.dumps(appState),
    "download.default_directory": downloadsFilePath,
    'download.prompt_for_download': False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    'safebrowsing.enabled': True
})
"""

prefs = {}
prefs['download.default_directory'] = os.path.abspath(downloadsFilePath)# + r"/"
prefs['printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState'] = json.dumps(appState)
#prefs['download.prompt_for_download'] = False
prefs['download.directory_upgrade'] = True
#prefs['safebrowsing.enabled'] = True
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')

#with webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver", options=options) as driver:
with webdriver.Chrome(service=fs.Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options) as driver:
    # 任意のHTMLの要素が特定の状態になるまで待つ
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    for url in urls:
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.get(url)
        # ページ上のすべての要素が読み込まれるまで待機
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located)
        # PDFとして印刷
        driver.execute_script('return window.print()')
        # 待機
        time.sleep(10)
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: 提示されたソースだと`downloadsFilePath = ''`と言う風にディレクトリ指定が空のようですが、質問時の転記ミスか情報隠しですか？ それから2つ目の参照記事は純粋にファイルのダウンロードのはずなので参考にはならないと思われます。 そしてもしかしたらこちらのJavaやC#の記事が何か参考になるかもしれません。[how to make headless chrome support window.print?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60463587/9014308), [Save as PDF using Selenium and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61798725/9014308)

Comment: `downloadsFilePath = '' `は情報隠しでした．純粋なファイルのダウンロードだけ上手くできるのが奇妙です…… PDFをダウンロードする方法を調べて出てくるほとんどのサイトが1つ目と同様な方法を使っているのでお手上げです．それと仮にこの問題が解決してもヘッドレスモードとの併用に頭を悩ませることが確定しているので憂鬱です．requestsを模索するのがいいのかもしれません．あと“paramsの設定が部分的に適応されていることから〜”の`params`は`prefs`の間違いでした．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows10の環境では、コメントで紹介した以下の記事にあった`savefile.default_directory`を設定することで指定したディレクトリにPDFファイルを保存することが出来ました。
[how to make headless chrome support window.print?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60463587/9014308)
[Save as PDF using Selenium and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61798725/9014308)

質問の紹介記事に掲載されていたプログラムで`chromedriver.exe`のパスを自分の環境に合わせたのと、
[[Python]Seleniumを利用したWebページのPDF保存方法 メモ](https://qiita.com/KWS_0901/items/33ae052e2e4694a6b4f1)

以下の部分の`download.default_directory`の行を

```
# ドライバへのPDF印刷設定の適用
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState":
    json.dumps(appState),
    "download.default_directory": '~/Downloads'
})
```

こんな風に`savefile.default_directory`と指定のディレクトリに変えただけです。

```
# ドライバへのPDF印刷設定の適用
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState":
    json.dumps(appState),
    "savefile.default_directory": r'C:\WebSiteLog'
})
```

試してみてください。

Comment: 解決しました．教えてもらった`savefile.default_directory `と`download.default_directory `を合わせたら2種類のPDFファイルをダウンロードできるようになりました．ありがとうございます！！！

Comment: `--headless`と`--kiosk-printing`を同時に使えました．